# Finding all Samba shares in local network

Tags: linux, networking, network-shares, samba

I would like to show all available samba shares in my local network (192.0.1.1/24 if I'm correct in specifying the network mask).

I've searched on this issue and tried things like `smbtree`, `findsmb`,  which returned nothing, and `nmblookup -S '*'`, which returned

> name_query failed to find name *

Seems like these commands worked in the past. I know that Samba shares exist on my network and I'm using some of them, but I would like to, for example, know the local IP address of my printer. So I'm wondering if there is a way to do this local network scan using standard Linux tools. If not, then I'd appreciate another tool suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those commands have fallen into disuse, with some secret parameters not being
maintained by new Linux developers.

The following command used to work but I couldn't make it work any more.
It might still work on some distributions:

```
nmblookup -S __SAMBA__
```

This one still works but not as good as before:

```
nmblookup -S WORKGROUP
```

If you wish to explore the network, you could start by nmapping and looking for
open port 139, assuming our LAN is 192.168.0.1-255 and we have 6 computers:

```
nmap -sS -O 192.168.0.1-6 -p 139
```

Once you know all the servers having the SAMBA port open,
the next stage is to find out what these machine's Netbios names are.
We'll start with the machine at 192.168.0.5:

```
nmblookup -A 192.168.0.5 -N
```

Now that we've got the computer name, say `COMPX`, to investigate its
shares use the diagnostic program `smbclient` with
the `-N` flag to suppress the password prompt (password not required):

```
smbclient -L \\COMPX -I 192.168.0.1 -N
```

(*The above programs might be different on various Linux distributions.*)

Comment: nowdays on `nmblookup -S WORKGROUP` works... sad...

Answer (score 2):

Steve Friedl's [nbtscan](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.htm) (last updated 2008-04) is a command-line tool that scans for open NETBIOS nameservers on a local or remote TCP/IP network, the first step in finding open shares. It is Windows [nbtstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/nbtstat) command, except it operates on a range of addresses and can also run on Linux.

###### Example

```
nbtscan 192.168.0.0/24
```

**Home Page:**   [nbtscan - NETBIOS nameserver scanner](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try using nmap with the smb-enum-shares script, like so:

```
nmap -p139,445 --script smb-enum-shares.nse --script-args smbusername=<USERNAME>,smbpass=<PASSWORD> <IP_OR_NETWORK>
```

You can leave out the part

```
--script-args smbusername=<USERNAME>,smbpass=<PASSWORD>
```

if you don't have any specific credentials.

https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-enum-shares.html